# Prove decomposition formula for $E^x(f(X_t);\tau_0<t)$, where $\tau_0$ denotes the first hitting time of $0$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expectation, stopping-times, stochastic-differential-equations

Let the strong Markov process $(X_t)_{0\le t\le T}$ be the unique week solution to the SDE

$$dX_s=\sigma(X_s)dB_s+CdL_s^0(X)$$
$$X_0=x \quad P^x-a.s.\quad(x>0)$$

Let $\tau_0$ be the first passage time of the process $(X_t)$ at point 0
$$\tau_0(X)=inf\{s>0,X_s=0\}\land T$$

Let $r_0^x$ be the density of $\tau_0$ under the probability $P^x$, I need to proove that
$$ E^x(f(X_t)\mathbb{1}_{\tau_0<t})=\int_0^tE^0f(X_{t-s})r_0^x(s)ds
    $$

Comment: ...And if you understand that, on each event $\{\tau_0=s\}$ with $s<t$, $X_t$ is distributed as $X_{t-s}$ under $P^0$, where is the problem?

Comment: On each event $\{\tau_0=s,s<t\}$, $E^xf(X_t)=E^0(X_{t-s})$ and we have $E^x(1_{\tau_0<t})=P^x(\tau_0<t)=\int^t_0r^x_0(s)ds$, I cant see how to get the expectation of the product!

Comment: Why on Earth would one be considering $\{\tau_0=s,s<t\}$? Note that $\{\tau_0=s,s<t\}=\{\tau_0=s\}$ when $s<t$ and that $\{\tau_0=s,s<t\}=\varnothing$ when $s\geqslant t$.

Comment: Ok I'll correct it,On each event $\{\tau_0=s\}$ whith s<t, $E^xf(X_t)=E^0(X_{t-s})$ and we have $E^x(1_{\tau_0<t})=P^x(\tau_0<t)=\int^t_0r^x_0(s)ds$, I cant see how to get the expectation of the product $E^x(f(X_t)1_{\tau<t})=$, maybe we use conditional expectation?

Comment: "maybe we use conditional expectation?" Indeed we should! And I do not understand why you keep replacing $\{\tau_0=s\}$ by $\{\tau_0<t\}$...